# Titanium Mobile Android [3.1.0]: Memory not released when app is closed

Tags: android, memory-management, titanium

I have an issue with the platform Titanium sdk 3.1.0 GA (I'm working on android)
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023762/titanium-mobile-android-memory-not-released-when-app-is-closed) link in which they talk about a bug related with the memory management of the platform.
In particular the app seems not to free the RAM when it is closed with the 'back button'.
The last answer to the question linked says 'it is a bug in Titanium 3.0.0.GA' and that this bug has been solved.
I suppose that this bug is still living in the 3.1.0 GA version of Titanium, is there somebody that has the same problem?

Thank you in advance,

Luca

Comment: I have also tried with the 3.1.2 version...but nothing has changed

Comment: The [jira ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12286) says its been solved, can you show code to reproduce this? And a log from Monitor or DDMS that shows the leak?

Comment: I noticed that this issue shows itself when I run demo application too (applications like "Master/Detail Application" or "Default Project").
Every time I close them (with the backbutton) when I do the next launch the applications occupy almost 2/3 mb then before.

Comment: I run Titanium studio under Ubuntu 10.10; I also tried with Titanium sdk 3.1.2 but without any result . The device on which I'm testing is a Samsung Galaxy Note II with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Could this just be the normal amount of usage? Since you hit back, doesn't android keep a copy of the app in memory until it needs to chuck it?

Comment: It could be but I have a lot of application that occupy the same amount of memory every time they run. I'm pretty sure this is a Titanium issue.